# I want to set a meta description by tag

Tags: html, css, blogger

For example, the name of the label is automobile. The page with the car label is **example.blogspot.com/search/label/automobile** , so I want to enter the meta description myself when I am on this page. How can I do it? I will use it for multiple tags. Example Meta description "This category will be car category."

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional tag for custom label mixed with meta tag description. Example:

```
<b:if cond='data:view.search.label == &quot;automobile&quot;'>
  <meta content='This category will be car category.' name='description'/>
</b:if>
```

Change 'automobile' in the `b:if` according to your tag name.

PS: It is recommended to place the meta description inside the head tag.